# Check whether the series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to check if the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (\frac{3n+1}{4n+1}\right )^{(-1)^nn}$$ converges or not.

I tried to apply the root test and I got the following: Let $a_n:=\left (\frac{3n+1}{4n+1}\right )^{(-1)^nn}$

We have that $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[n]{\left |\left (\frac{3n+1}{4n+1}\right )^{(-1)^nn}\right |}=\sqrt[n]{\left (\frac{3n+1}{4n+1}\right )^{(-1)^nn}}=\left (\frac{3n+1}{4n+1}\right )^{(-1)^n}$$ 
Can we continue from here? Or do we have to apply an other convergence criterium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary condition for convergence is: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = 0$, which is clearly not the case here. So the series will not converge.

In other words it won't converge because every term is positive and for all $n = 2k+1$,  $a_{n} > 1$, so you are adding at least 1 infinitely many times to your sum.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For $\sum a_n$ to converge we need $a_n\to 0$.

This is not the case here since for $n$ odd then $a_n=\left(\dfrac{4n+1}{3n+1}\right)^n\ge 1$

So the series is not convergent.

Comment: I got it!! thank you very much!! :-)